# Add row to grid panel, but with separate construction details in ExtJS

Tags: combobox, extjs

I have generated grid panel based on my results in PHP. Here is a grid panel: [myGridPanel](http://s47.radikal.ru/i115/1008/57/d7da409cce5b.png).
Now I need to create third row in grid panel and place `Ext.form.ComboBox` inside this third row. There should be a `Ext.form.ComboBox` for every column.

**NB!** Not one combobox, but a number of them for every column, but only in third row.

I thought about applying editor to this grid panel columns like [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html), but as you can see this means, that all rows will have `Ext.form.ComboBox`, but I need them only in third row. Third row shouldn't have any content except those `Ext.form.ComboBox` with their data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add a renderer for that column (in ColumnModel) and try to give the column value (which can probably be everything) depending on which line you are rendering. E.g.:

```
function renderTestColumn(value, p, record, store) {
    return value;
}
```

Here you can find all params passed to renderer function:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/ColumnModel.html#method-Ext.grid.ColumnModel-setRenderer

Comment: No no. I know about renderers. Here I need to add a row and I need to place a ComboBox under every column in that third row.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a PropertyGrid to the layout. So now it's

```
Parent - layout : 'border'
| - 'center' : GridPanel
| - 'east' : PropertyGrid
```

Now I have same ComboBoxes in this property grid and parent is `xtype : 'form'`. So now sending setup data from suggestions about GridPanel which were set in PropertyGrid is not a problem.

Adding separate row to GridPanel is to difficult for me yet.